# Using coinmp.dll on windows

Tags: python, windows, optimization

I try to set up a simple environment to solve linear programming problem using Pulp and CoinMP.dll . I can't make it work. Can anyone help?

First thing when i try to run the test here is what i have

> Solver pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD unavailable.  Solver
>   pulp.solvers.CPLEX_DLL unavailable. Solver pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD
>   unavailable. Solver pulp.solvers.CPLEX_PY unavailable.
>
> ```
> Solver pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD unavailable.
>          Testing zero subtraction
>          Testing continuous LP solution
>          Testing maximize continuous LP solution
>          Testing unbounded continuous LP solution
>                  Error in CoinMP it reports Optimal
>          Testing Long Names
>          Testing repeated Names Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "D:\Portable Python
> 2.7.5.1\app\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 2235, in pulpTestAll
>     pulpTestSolver(s)   File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\app\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pulp\tests.py", line 560, in pulpTestSol r
>     t(solver(msg=msg))   File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\app\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pulp\tests.py", line 170, in pulpTest014
>     pulpTestCheck(prob, solver, [LpStatusOptimal], {x:4, y:-1, z:6, w:0})   File "D:\Portable Python
> 2.7.5.1\app\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pulp\tests.py", line 17, in pulpTestChec
>     prob.writeLP("debug.lp")   File "D:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\app\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 1502, in writeLP
>     + str(repeated_names)) pulp.constants.PulpError: Repeated variable names in Lp format [('x', 2)]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the issue. PulpTest014 throws this exception. To fix it COINMP_DLL should be placed in the array containing all solvers throwing an exception (as COIN_CMD already is)

```
if solver.__class__ in [COIN_CMD, COINMP_DLL, PULP_CBC_CMD, CPLEX_CMD, CPLEX_PY,
        GLPK_CMD, GUROBI_CMD]:
    try:
        pulpTestCheck(prob, solver, [LpStatusOptimal], {x:4, y:-1, z:6, w:0})
    except PulpError:
        #these solvers should raise an error'
        pass
```

With that TestAll passes.